# not able to get input box using FormArray in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

My html template is

```
    <button (click)="addAdd()">Add Address</button>     
<div formArrayName="address">
    <div *ngFor="let add of personalForm.controls?.user?.address?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="personalForm.controls.address.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeAdd(i)"></span>
            <label>Country</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="country" placeholder="Country"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Json is

```
personalData =  {address:[{country: "IN", state: "MH"}, {country: "IN", state: "NA"}], faname: "xyz"}
```

I am not able to get input box in html page what i am doing wrong?
i want to put for loop in personalData.address and needs to open existing data in input box as well as if i want to increase array that is working on when do i click on addAdd()

Comment: You're mixing reactive form elements (formArrayName, formControlName) with templa-driven form elements (ngModel). It's one or the other. And your JSON is irrelevant. What matters is the definition of your form group. Post a complete minimal example  reproducing the problem.

Comment: so instead of [(ngModel)] what should i used ? i want to get values from API json and needs show that values in input fields .

Comment: If you have to ask that, then you should refrain from using form arrays from now, and start by learning the basics of Angular forms, frm a good book, or from the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

i missed controls in between user and address `<div *ngFor="let add of personalForm.controls?.user?.controls?.address?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">`

and its solved !